# Change name of uploaded file

Tags: php, image

I have been trying to change the name of a file after an upload with my script.
I want every file to be named as "testing". Later I am going to change "testing" to a
variable that gets a unique name. Now I just want to change the name to "testing".

Also the script always says error although the file are uploaded. 
Can I get some help here please?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$uploadDir = 'images/'; //Image Upload Folder
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$fileName = $_FILES['Photo']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['Photo']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['Photo']['type'];
$filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
$result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);
if (!$result) {
echo "Error uploading file";
exit;
}
if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
}
$query = "INSERT INTO $db_table ( Image ) VALUES ('$filePath')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 
}
?>
```

Comment: says what error ?! Specify the current error in order to get any help. Maybe you would need a native error from the mysql driver instead of "error query failed" custom one

Comment: Says "Error uploading filr" I tried to put $Sucess "Done" in the right way but it still gets the echo "Error uploading file";

Comment: give us the output of `var_dump($_FILES)` and of `$filepath`

Comment: "/images" or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: the var dump of $_FILES and $filepath

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
$fileName = "testing"; //maybe add extension
```

instead of getting original filename from `$_FILES`. Although after the file is moved you may end up with a situation of overwriting existing files as they all has the same name. To prevent that (for testing purposes) you may add something to `$fileName`, maybe a short random string.